# What do the GCGenerationInfo instances in GCMemoryInfo.GenerationInfo represent?

Tags: .net-core, garbage-collection

I am using the new GetGCMemoryInfo static method off of the GC class in .NET to to debug some memory usage in my ASP.NET Core application. I thought I understood what the GenerationInfo span represented, namely the number of bytes allocated by each generation and the fragmentation of each generation before and after the garbage collector runs. However, it seems to be something slightly different because the SizeBeforeBytes for example only continue to increase as my app runs even though my heap size is not growing and using another memory profiler such as dotMemory shows that garbage collection is being run and the generations are being collected and shrunk as expected. I drew this inference based on this blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-updated-getgcmemoryinfo-api-in-net-5-0-and-how-it-can-help-you/. It is also odd that there 5 fixed entries, even though there are only "4" generations if you include the large object heap.

Comment: *"`SizeBeforeBytes` for example only continue to increase"* - are you sure it is really increase or it is just fluctuation in a stable app where GC is triggered because of the size periodically hits some thresholds. And if you use .NET 5+, there is also Pinned Object Heap reported as generation "5".

Comment: @KonradKokosa it was definitely increasing every time to actually very large numbers of GB, and thanks for clarifying about the pinned object heap, I had missed that one being a thing.

Comment: I noticed that same thing in my app… SizeBeforeBytes/SizeAfterBytes returned by this API are huge, other tools like PerfView, windbg etc. report much smaller and realistic numbers. Also the sum of all generation sizes did not equate HeapSizeBytes returned in the same call (should it?)

Comment: Yes, that was a bug as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75091461/mysterious-very-large-wrong-number-reported-by-getgcmemoryinfo-gcgenerationi